# Not sure what's going on with my DataGrid controls' appearance

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` control on the main window of my WPF application.  My app has a "Day mode" and a "Night mode", as it runs in police cars and it needs a more subdued and not so bright color scheme for night time use.  The thing is that the first row of data entered into the `DataGrid` when in night mode ends up having a white background, and I have no idea where its coming from.

I've got Snoop installed but for some reason my program's main window does not show up in the list of windows Snoop recognizes as a WPF window, so it's useless.  I did upgrade to 3.8, which I believe is the most recent version, and still no joy.

I know that the `DataGrid's SelectedIndex` property is -1, so it's not a selected row.  And I have other color choices in my program for a selected row.  I have no idea what the control is trying to display and why it would make the background white.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please put up XAML for the data grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of things going on here.

It turns out that the cause of the white background in the `DataGrid` is described [in this tutorial.](http://wpftutorial.net/MergedDictionaryPerformance.html)  To fix it, I moved my styles up a level in the merged resource directory tree.

The problem with Snoop was caused by running VS as an administrator but running Snoop as a normal user.  Running Snoop as an administrator allows it to see my program and interact with it.